# How do I change my app.config setting using transformation syntax?

Tags: asp.net, app-config, transformation, web-config-transform, web.config-transform

I have this that I would like to exchange from my app.config. It is the VALUE that is the one that is exchanged. How will I write that in my app.sys.config?

```
 <userSettings>   
   <Ska.Base.Properties.Settings>
     <setting name="DataSource" serializeAs="String">
        <value>nc2221.rsss.st</value>
     </setting>
</Ska.Base.Properties.Settings>

<Ska.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="Plu_DnsName" serializeAs="String">
    <value>10.11.10.113</value>
  </setting>
</Ska.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```

this is what it should be in my app after transformation

```
<userSettings>   
   <Ska.Base.Properties.Settings>
     <setting name="DataSource" serializeAs="String">
        <value>nb2222.rsss.st</value>
     </setting>
</Ska.Base.Properties.Settings>

<Ska.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="Plu_DnsName" serializeAs="String">
    <value>10.33.20.123</value>
  </setting>
</Ska.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```

This is how I would like to use it. But i dont understand how to do it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx

since the string is outside the parameter (value)

This will work but this is not what I am after. (Attribute vs property)

```
<userSettings>   
<Ska.Base.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="DataSource" 
            serializeAs="String"
            value="<userSettings>   
<Ska.Base.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="DataSource" 
            serializeAs="String"
            value="nc2221.rsss.st"
            xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" 
            xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
</Ska.Base.Properties.Settings>

 <Ska.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="Plu_DnsName" 
            serializeAs="String"
            value = "10.11.10.113"
            xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" 
            xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
 </Ska.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
```

Comment: You are lacking some essential information here: What have you tried so far? How do you want to accomplish this (using a stand along app, directly from the asp.net app, ...)? Why not just edit them manually, doesn't seem to be a huge deal. Also, what do you mean by "transformation syntax"??

Comment: Also you have 18 asked questions so far, but you have marked none of them as answered. Could you please mark an answer as such if it helped you? And if not please specify your problem more clearly

Answer (score 2):

and finally I found an answer:

```
 <userSettings>   
<Ska.Base.Properties.Settings>
<setting name="DataSource" 
        serializeAs="String"
        value="<userSettings>   
<Ska.Base.Properties.Settings>
<setting name="DataSource" 
        serializeAs="String"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" 
        xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
  <value xdt:Transform="Replace">nc2221.rsss.st</value>
  </setting>
</Ska.Base.Properties.Settings>

<Ska.Properties.Settings>
 <setting name="Plu_DnsName" 
        serializeAs="String"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" 
        xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
  <value xdt:Transform="Replace">10.11.10.113</value>
 </setting>
</Ska.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```